# UI stops responding when adding items to a BindableCollection only when the view is opened a second time

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application using the Caliburn.Micro framework, there is a ViewModel with associated View, there are several properties in the viewmodel to hold the results of a database call, they use BindableCollection for the models. When the view is opended for the first time everything works perfectly - no lockups / freezing of the app. If I close the view and reopen it the app stops responding when it tries to add the first item from the database to the BindableCollection.

This is the code in the ViewModel

```
public class CallLoggingViewModel : Screen
{
    private BindableCollection<Site> _sites;
    private ICollectionView _siteList;

    public BindableCollection<Site> Sites
    { 
        get { return _sites; }
        set 
        { 
            _sites = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Sites); 
        }   
    }

    public ICollectionView SiteList
    {
        get { return _siteList; }
        set
        {
            _siteList = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SiteList);
        }
    }

    public CallLoggingViewModel(SimpleContainer container, IFMSDataHandler dataHandler, ILog logger)
    {
        _container = container;
        _dataHandler = dataHandler;
        _logger = logger;
        
        DisplayName = "Call Logging";
        IsTabCloseButtonVisible = true;

        _sw = new Stopwatch();
        _sw.Start();
        Task[] tasks = new Task[1]
        {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSites()),
            //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetStandardCallCodes()),
            //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetEngineers()),
            //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetCallPriority())
        };

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        _sw.Stop();
        _logger.Info("Finished Setting up");
    }

    private async Task GetSites()
    {
        try
        {
            Sites = new BindableCollection<Site>();
            var sites = await _dataHandler.GetSites(_currentUser.ToString());

            foreach (var site in sites)
            {
                Sites.Add(site);
            }

            SiteList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Sites);

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                SiteList.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                SiteList.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SiteName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

There are 158 items in the results from the database. It makes no difference if the View is bound to the Sites or SiteList collections, or even (for test purposes) not bound at all, so it doesn't appear to be a binding issue.

Can someone help me understand why this works on the first time but not the second? Thanks

Comment: `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` is blocking call, why do you need it?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I wanted to make sure the data was available before continuing - is there a method that doesn't block?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I've changed to a Task.WhenAll(tasks) and this has solved the problem, thanks for the pointer. I'm confused as to why I was getting a problem with Task.WaitAll only on the second time of opening the view.

Comment: You also don't need the for loop... 
var sites = await _dataHandler.GetSites(_currentUser.ToString());
Sites = new BindableCollection<Site>(sites);